# "As + adjective "

Tags: adjectives, metaphors

1) I found him dead.

2) He painted the car red.

3) He will make them strong.

I get confused using adjective in these typs of sentences for being a non native speaker because sometimes some sentences sound bad to me. So I use a trick to understand whether it's correct or not.

4) I found him as dead.

5) He painted the car as red.

6) He will make them as strong.

I use "as " before adjective.  If it makes sense to me with using "as", then without as it should be correct too. It's just my presumption.

My question is,  Are my three sentences [4,5,6 ] perfectly correct?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you picked up your "trick," but the insertion of the word *as* does not make sentences 4, 5, and 6 correct. In order to be correct, those sentences could be edited as follows (these are just suggestions):

> I found him as dead as Osama bin Laden.
>
> He painted the car as red as a monkey's butt.
>
> He will make them as strong as Hercules.

As for sentences 1, 2, and 3, they may not sound correct to you now, but in time they will, as you become more proficient with English.

Comment: I personally think you should write a book for English beginners. This is the answer that I wanted to write.